# Foreign key field in Child data source is not filling when the data source joined with Outer join link in D365 F&O

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-365-operations

I have created a simple table SaleslineEx. which has a foreign key relationship with the SalesLine table.

[image: SalesLineEx FK relation]

[image: SalesLineEx datsource with outer join]

When trying to create a new record in the sales line, the **SalesLineEx** **sales line** field does not populate with the sales line record.

[image: Empty value in salesline field]

I have tried different solutions from the blogs but they are not working. Can anyone give me a solution?

Comment: How are the records in your new table created?

Comment: I am adding a new line in sales line in sales order form and filling the values in new table fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by creating the mapping between my extension table and the `SalesLine`using `SysExtensionSerializerExtensionMap`.
[image: Mapping node]

[image]

After adding the mappings create an Extension class for the `SalesLine` table, and create a COC method for the `insert` method. Call the insert operation of the Extension table after the next call of the sales line `insert` method, using `SysExtensionSerializerExtensionMap` class from the extension table buffer is shown below.

```
next insert(_dropInvent, _findMarkup, _childBuffer, _skipCreditLimitCheck, _skipWHSProcesses, _interCompanyInventTransId);

    if(FormDataUtil::isFormDataSource(this))
    {
        SalesLineExt salesLineExt = this.SysExtensionSerializerMap::getExtensionTable(tableNum(SalesLineExt));
        salesLineExt.SysExtensionSerializerExtensionMap::insertAfterBaseTable(this);
    }
```

[image: SalesLineExtesnionCalss]

[image: COCForInsertMethod]